# Set Starttime and Endtime in quickfixj config in different timezone

Tags: quickfixj

My project use quickfixj to connect with my client in HongKong, config starttime and endtime in client is set: 08:01 – 21:30 HKT.

I config server is:(My timezone UTC +7)

```
StartTime=23:55:00
EndTime=14:35:00
```

In by default UTC +0 but connect failed.

My config is true?

Comment: Do you have CheckLatency flag?

Comment: Please add CheckLatency=N and show me the result

Comment: Or using CheckLatency=Y and MaxLatency

Answer (score 1):

I set CheckLatency=N. Here my configuation:

```
[default]
ConnectionType=acceptor
StartTime=04:05:00
EndTime=12:00:00
EncryptMethod=0
UseDataDictionary=Y
CheckLatency=N
CheckCompID=N

FileStorePath=.\fixacceptor
FileLogPath=.\logacceptor
FileLogHeartbeats=Y
FileIncludeMilliseconds=Y
FileIncludeTimeStampForMessages=Y
FileStoreMaxCachedMsgs=0

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=FixAcceptor
TargetCompID=FixClient8080
SocketAcceptPort=5001
ClosedResendInterval=Y
DataDictionary=.\FIX42.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
SendRedundantResendRequests=Y
```